Propane Gas Line Through Exterior wall into cabinet below cooktop
I am curious what I would use to stub out for future propane gas in my kitchen. I have 2x6 exterior walls.
I will have a large propane tank sitting on the exterior wall and want the gas line ran from outside, directly into the cabinet below the cooktop. I can't have it go under the floor as there is a slab. It just needs to be a straight 8" pipe.
A qualified individual will install the propane tank and the cooktop, but I need to stub this out this weekend so siding can go up and around the exterior stub out.
Any advice is welcome.

When we added propane, the propane installer just drilled a hole through the siding and wall and placed the pipe right through.  They sealed up the space with a bit of silicon.  Ask your instaler what is required.

Exactly, just like the cable installer, etc. They do this all the time.

I didn't think about this. Thanks!

Plus, positioning varies… your jurisdiction might require an accessible shutoff in an adjacent cabinet. (Maybe not if you have a shutoff outside, but you never know…)
